# Do DCT results contain phase spectrum?

Tags: python, phase, amplitude, dct, scipy

I've been working much with `numpy.fft` lately where just like [the documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.fft.html#module-numpy.fft) says:

> When the input a is a time-domain signal and `A = fft(a)`, `np.abs(A)` is its amplitude spectrum and `np.abs(A)**2` is its power spectrum. The phase spectrum is obtained by `np.angle(A)`.

Then I took a look at DCT, but I could not figure out how to derive the phase from the results, because only real values are contained, so the `np.angle()` will be $0$. From the FFT results I can take out interesting elements, calculate amplitude, phase and plot them as cosines:

```
[A*np.cos(2*np.pi*f*t + ph) for t in range(N)]
```

where `A` is the amplitude, `f` is the frequency, `ph` is the phase-shift and `t` is the variable, i.e. time. So my question is: can the same be derived from DCT results and how?

Comment: Delta = p1 ~p2 - (p<--i -1)
In same place

Comment: @hassani What exactly are trying to suggest here? Please explain what you wrote.

Comment: @hassani Sounds cryptic

Answer (score 4):

Not really, as the transform is real. However, one could interpret the sign as a poor man's phase, being "quantized" or restricted to values $0$ or $\pi$. In other words, $1 = 1.e^{0.\imath}$ and $-1 = 1.e^{\pi.\imath}$.

[EDIT] There are some instances where people use the sign of DCT or (real) wavelet coefficients, for subpixel image registration or matching, as alluded to in [DCT Sign Only Correlation and Its Application to Image Registration](https://doi.org/10.1109/APCCAS.2006.342490):

> In the DCT case, all DCT coefficients are real values, as a result,
>   the phase information corresponds to the sign of DCT coefficients.

Comment: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/224711136_DCT_Sign-Only_Correlation_with_Application_to_Image_Matching_and_the_Relationship_with_Phase-Only_Correlation article without the **** paywall

Comment: I do prefer to provide the DOI, with is likely to last, then everybody has means to find the pape, see for instance [How does LibGen/SciHub affect researchers' research and publishing process?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/68243/38057)

Answer (score 4):

A DCT is equivalent to a DFT of real data that is doubled and mirrored, thus rendering it symmetric.  The DFT of any symmetric real signal has a phase of zero (its all cosines, no antisymmetric sine components).

Comment: Does this mean that DCT assumes that all cosines start at (0, Ak) where Ak is the component's amplitude?

Comment: Only cosine that starts at 0 with a phase of 0 (or Pi) is symmetric around 0.